# PHP mb substring functionality with emoji's

Tags: php, emoji, multibyte

I have a text

> @Mention text

And I have $start and $length values for @Mention text part, but I am unable to change the text correctly, when string contains emoticons, it is few letter ahead

javascript is passing $start and length from text, it understands

```
$start = " @Mention ".indexOf('@') //9
```

Result what I need is something like

```
 <span>@Mention text</span>
```

What is the correct function in PHP, with what I can substring replace text.
I've looked online, but no solution

Current output

```
 @Ment<span>ion text</span>
```

---

```
$formatted = ' @Mention text ';
$content = $this->mb_substr_replace(
                    $formatted ?: '',
                    "<span class='mention-link'>" . mb_substr($formatted ?: '', $mention->getStart() ?: 0, $mention->getLength() ?: 0, 'UTF-8') . "</span>",
                    9,
                    5,
                    'UTF-8'
                );
```

and the function itself

```
public function mb_substr_replace($string,$replacement,$start,$length=null,$encoding = null){
    if ($encoding == null){
        if ($length == null){
            return mb_substr($string,0,$start).$replacement;
        }
        else{
            return mb_substr($string,0,$start).$replacement.mb_substr($string,$start + $length);
        }
    }
    else{
        if ($length == null){
            return mb_substr($string,0,$start,$encoding).$replacement;
        }
        else{
            return mb_substr($string,0,$start,$encoding). $replacement. mb_substr($string,$start + $length,mb_strlen($string,$encoding),$encoding);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a code sample. What is the value of `$start`? How did you get it?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: Your question is unclear as what is the current result of the code.

Comment: Edited post, it should be clear now

Comment: You're getting the offset in Javascript? That's going to be an issue (because JS treats the string as UTF-16 units, while PHP will either treat it as bytes or correctly per character, depending on how you approach it). `9` does not correspond to the correct offset in any straight forward way. You should not mix Javascript and PHP string manipulation functions, or you need to standardise on a specific value for how offset is being calculated.

Comment: There is 1 more problem, that offset comes from iOS app, that i do not own nor develop, and it sends the same offset number, it has to work on both (web and iOS app), if iOS works, web is broken and the other way around too

Comment: So, the offsets are pretty much always wrong, and you need to know in what way they're wrong so you can compensate for it in PHP…? Sounds like a terrible situation that should be rectified at the source primarily.